# problems formatting dates in polish

Tags: c#, datetimepicker, datetime-format, polish

I am having problems with date formatting for a website aimed at Polish Clients. When entering a calendar entry it is switching the month and the date. e.g it puts the entry in 7th September instead of 9th July.

The problem seems to be a datetime.parse statement as follows

```
DateTime.Parse(txtCalendarDate.Text)
```

This supposedly uses the current culture which is Polish. Polish has the day/month the right way round so why is it switching them?

Please assist.

Comment: What is the value of `txtCalendarDate.Text` _exactly_ and what is your `CurrentCulture`?

Comment: 09/07/2015. The current culture is pl-PL

Comment: Why don't you use `txtCalendarDate.Value` which is _already_ a `DateTime`?

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved this by doing System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern = "dd/MM/yyyy"; in my global.asax. It was yyyy/MM/dd for Polish